# Generating an address from a public key in C++

Tags: addresses, keccak

Example:

Input key = `0x025f37d20e5b18909361e0ead7ed17c69b417bee70746c9e9c2bcb1394d921d4ae`

Output address = `0xd09D3103CcABfb769eDc3e9B01500Ca7241D470A`

I have been using an algorithm from `keccak-tiny.c` by David Leon Gil, with the following change:

Padding with `0x01` instead of `0x06`: 7 bytes of message "testing" give me `5f16f4c7f149ac4f9510d9cf8cf384038ad348b3bcdc01915f95de12df9d1b02` as is in "Which cryptographic hash function does Ethereum use?"

In "Generating an address from a public key" is algorithm, but I have questions:

- how exactly means getPublic,keyFromPublic ?
- before keccak I must convert from a 33-byte key to a 65-byte key (address will be compact-independent) or keccak is applied on hex string text form, not bytes?
- how checksum address with upper/lower case?

How to do it with C++?

Comment: I tried my best fixing up your question, but your description is a MESS!

Comment: There's a similar question for javascript https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29476/generating-an-address-from-a-public-key

Answer (score 1):

Is solved: as is in"How are ethereum addresses generated?" we have 4 steps:

```
1. convert to 65 byte uncompressed key
2. removed first "04" byte, we have 5f37d20e5b18909361e0ead7ed17c69b417bee70746c9e9c2bcb1394d921d4ae612d83e3487012034792ff36357ee25f382913cfeb54a8622b7ef35d635d8740 for 0x025f37d20e5b18909361e0ead7ed17c69b417bee70746c9e9c2bcb1394d921d4ae
3. Keccak this 64 bytes to 32 bytes: 81862025a6a8b333133c9b9ad09d3103ccabfb769edc3e9b01500ca7241d470a
4. Get last 20 bytes: 0xd09D3103CcABfb769eDc3e9B01500Ca7241D470A
```