# Python | eth_utils | Public Ethereum Address derivation from Public key not working

Tags: python, public-key, keccak

I have the below, trying to derive the Ethereum Address from public key (working) using keccak and to_checksum_address on eth_util, but doesn't match up with derivation on [iancoleman.io](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/) or [miguelmota.com](https://lab.miguelmota.com/ethereum-public-key-to-address/example/)

```
        # Derive the public key from the BIP32 extended key (working ✅)
        public_key_bytes = binascii.unhexlify(bip32_extended_key.PublicKey().hex())

        # Compute the Keccak-256 hash of the public key
        public_key_hash = keccak(public_key_bytes)

        # Take the last 20 bytes of the public key hash (the Ethereum address)
        address_bytes = public_key_hash[-20:]

        # Convert the address bytes to a hex string
        address_hex = address_bytes.hex()

        # Convert the hex address to a checksummed Ethereum address
        EthereumAddress = to_checksum_address('0x' + address_hex)

        if EthereumAddress == target_address:
            print("Seed phrase:", seed_phrase)
            print("Address:", target_address)
            print("Target address reached!")
            exit()
        else:
            print("Public key: ", public_key_bytes.hex())
            print("Ethereum address: ", EthereumAddress)
```

Comment: I'd check the intermediate steps for some possible issues with mixing hex string with raw bytes and/or reversing the byte order.

Comment: thank you @Ismael, seems you've already answered this 6 years ago here (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29476/generating-an-address-from-a-public-key#comment31429_29480) hugely appreciated.

In the process of attempting to cleanly deriving the public key in uncompressed format..

Comment: Giving up on this for now, can't seem to find a way to derive an uncompressed public key from extended key needing 65 bytes instead of 33..'0x' instead of eg '02'..